# Is this line necessary in the following Assembly Program?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm pretty new at ALP and while looking at this program I found a line I think is unnecessary and can just simply be removed, changing a few lines.

Here's the code:

```
DATA SEGMENT
  N1 DW 2804H
  N2 DW 4213H
  BCD_SUM DW ?
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS: CODE, DS: DATA
START: MOV AX, DATA
  MOV DS, AX
  MOV AX, N1
  MOV BX, N2
  ADD AL, BL
  DAA
  MOV CL, AL
  MOV AL, AH    ; Here I have Problem
  ADD AL, BH
  DAA
  MOV CH, AL
  MOV BCD_SUM, CX
  MOV AH, 4CH
  INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Why not do just `add ah, bh`?
Moving higher byte at `AX` to lower, then adding, is there any reason for this or can I just simply change it?

Comment: `DAA` works with `AL`. You have to move the result there. You can - like here - move `AH`to `AL` before doing the addition. Or you can - like your suggestion - do the addition first, but afterwards you must move `AH` to `AL`.

Comment: Thanks so I can do that but still need to move it all for using daa

Comment: Yes. The question is wether you need later the original `AH`. This isn't the case, so both solutions are equivalent.

Comment: took me a while to figure out what "ALP" means. I would suggest to stop using this acronym and just spell out the words. It's not like you badly need to save space here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the code is *currently* written, that instruction is necessary because it puts the desired value in the `AL` register, in preparation for subsequent instructions. The `ADD` instruction following it uses the value from `AL` explicitly, as does the next `DAA` instruction (implicitly).

Just to make sure we're on the same page, and for the benefit of future readers, let's go through the code and annotate it:

```
; Set the segment register 'DS' to the constant value 'DATA'
; (indirectly via 'AX', since you can't move an immediate into a segment register).
MOV AX, DATA
MOV DS, AX

; Put the constant values 'N1' and 'N2' into the 'AX' and 'BX' registers, respectively.
MOV AX, N1
MOV BX, N2

; Add the lower 8 bits of 'BX' to the lower 8 bits of 'AX'.
ADD AL, BL

; Using the results of that last addition ('AL' and flags),
; adjust for packed binary-coded decimal arithmetic.
DAA

; Save the result (from 'AL') in 'CL' (since 'AL' is about to be clobbered).
MOV CL, AL

; Having just done the low 8 bits of 'AX' ('AL'), we are now going to do
; the high 8 bits ('AH'). But because the DAA instruction uses 'AL'
; as an implicit operand, we first need to swap 'AL' and 'AH'.
MOV AL, AH
ADD AL, BH
DAA

; Just like we saved the result of the low 8 bits in 'CL',
; save the result of the high 8 bits in 'CH'.
MOV CH, AL

; Now, the result is in 'CX' (low byte in 'CL', high byte in 'CH'),
; so store/save it into the WORD-sized variable 'BCD_SUM'.
MOV BCD_SUM, CX

; Call DOS interrupt to terminate the process.
; 
; Note that there is a bug here: you should be setting the 'AL' register
; to the process's return code. You could do this explicitly with a
; 'MOV AL, ReturnCode' instruction, or you could just do
; 'MOV AX, 4C00h' to set both halves at once.
MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
```

Hopefully now you see the logic of the original code, and why it's written the way it is. It loads full, WORD-sized values into the `AX` and `BX` registers, and then it does a packed, binary-coded decimal arithmetic operation on the low BYTE (lower 8 bits) and the high BYTE. Finally, it saves the result as a full, WORD-sized value in `BCD_SUM`, indirectly through `CX` as a scratch register.

Now, you certainly could write the same code a different way, yet still accomplish the same task. This is basically what you suggest in the question—reordering the instructions, so that you have:

```
ADD AH, BH     ; add high bytes first
MOV AL, AH     ; swap order of bytes
DAA            ; adjust result of addition, now in AL
```

However, there is absolutely no advantage to writing the code like this. It's just a matter of personal choice, and which one you think is more clear.

*Personally*, I would prefer setting up the registers *first* (as in the original code), and then executing `ADD` and `DAA` back-to-back. Why? Because `DAA` depends on *flags* that are set implicitly by the `ADD` instruction (specifically, the auxiliary carry flag, `AF`). While `MOV` instructions don't clobber the flags, *most* other instructions do, so getting into the habit of separating `ADD` and `DAA` instructions risks introducing a difficult-to-find bug.

The only possible advantage of rearranging instructions like this is to alleviate data dependencies, and thus increase the execution speed of the code. That won't happen here, though, since you've still got an unbroken dependency chain between these three instructions.

Comment: Thanks this answer really helped to learn much more about ALP